# ClearCase-ClearQuest UCM- check-in done by other user user

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearquest

I have CC-CQ integration enabled.

Let's say Record 1 is approved to user A and Record 2 is approved to User B. When user B attempted to check-in some changes using Record 2 for which he/she is the owner( by selecting Record 2 in check-in window), actual check-in happened on Record 1 - which should NOT be the case. Please help me to understand how does this happen and how can it be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen unless there are changes by user C which have dependencies to both Record 1 and Record 2.   One of the weaknesses of UCM, if you want to call it that, it the ability to keep changes atomic when subsequent changes occur which touch both Record 1 and 2.

Designing components which are truly standalone will help with these kinds of conflicts but will not completely eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

This also sounds like a shared-stream configuration.... Generally, the only time that this is even an option is if the checkins are in a shared stream. Either a single-stream project, or a shared stream. Can you please also mention the ClearCase version and the interface you're using? There are 2 eclipse-based remote clients, the ClearCase explorer GUI, and the various development tool integrations, and their behaviors can be subtly different.